# can't retrieve id from mysql into hidden input element

Tags: php, mysql

I've such a situation , want to retrieve row ids from mysql to input hidden elements. let's take a look at script

php =>

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("host","user","pswd","db");

if (isset($_POST['some'])){
    echo $_POST['some'];
}

echo "<form name='a' method='post' action='index.php'";

if (!$con->connect_error){
    if ($con->set_charset("utf8")){
        if ($r = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tb")){
            while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='some' value='" . $row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' id='j'>" . $row['file_title'] . "</a><br>";
            }
            $r->free();
        }
    }
}

echo "</form>";
?>
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("j").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.a.submit();
});
</script>
```

from this script I'm expect that when I'll click to `$row['file_title']` it must `echo clicked row id` but it get id only from first element and this id belongs to last row in database. what is wrong here , how can I solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: the problem here is, that you have multiple "a" tags with the same id ("j") and name ("some"), assuming that your "tb" table has more than one row.
That is probably why its always the id of the last entry that is echoed.

Comment: just remove the javascript and then try let be submit button

Comment: now remembered , thanks , but how I know name repeat is common in elements , doesn't it ? (id must be changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here while loop is overwriting hidden element and link Ids every time.

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='some' value='" . $row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' id='j'>" . $row['file_title'] . "</a><br>";
            }
```

See, Here every link has id 'j'. Every input element has name 'some'.
Better is to assign a class on this link and append $row['id'] in hidden element name in order to make elements unique like this :

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='some_".$row['id']."' value='" . $row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' class="alink" id='j_".$row['id']."'>" . $row['file_title'] . "</a><br>";
                }
```

Javascript will be something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementsByClassName("alink").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.a.submit();
});

</script>
```

where 'alink' is the class assigned to the link.

Hope, it'll help you..

Comment: This is all clear , but how can I know with php value of the hidden element ? (in this case I don't know exact name of  the hidden element)

Comment: You can get it using jquery selector. When you click on a link, here hidden element is its siblig, so you can get the name of just first sibling of that clicked link

Comment: can you show with example ? I'm not quite well with jQuery , thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Here is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/pUBVS/ you can check here, how to get the values of siblings and for more details, visit : http://api.jquery.com/prev/.

Answer (score 0):

How knows the script which link was clicked? All links submit the *same form* and all `<input>`s in your form have the *same name*!
You could either put each `<input>` and associated `<a>` in a separate form or give each `<input>` a unique name. And of course you also have to adapt your JavaScript, because `document.getElementById('j')` will only fetch the first link.